# Guest is disabled but somewhere still active

Tags: onepage-checkout, onestepcheckout

I've the **Allow guest checkout** to **NO**, but sometimes I get a Guest Sale. I don't know where is this possible, I've been looking in the whole website and there is only the checkout with Log In option.

Is there any way that the user buy without registering? Or is any way to register all user activity to know what steps were made?

Comment: are you using any checkout extension?

Comment: Yes, sorry not no say that before: I'm using [Lotus Breath -> One Step Checkout] (https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/lotusbreath-one-step-checkout.html)

Comment: can you disable that extension and check , may be issue is causing from that..... you can disable by `app/etc/modules` folder.....

Comment: It's happening only once in a week or more. I can't reproduce the problem, because every 20 purchases one is a Guest. Maybe it's a browser problem or a unknown combination of actions that make magento (or the extension), that's why I'm asking for a logging system (or any idea) to try to know whats happening. Thanks

Comment: @paupro Did you find any solution to this?